# Grails Asset Pipeline: URLs within static assets

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline

In Grails Asset Pipeline, I am serving HTML, js, CSS, and image files.

In an HTML asset, if I need to supply a src for an image, how should I write that URL to take into account:

1. that assets might be served from a different base URL, as specified by `grails.assets.url`
2. that assets might be served from the Grails server (in dev mode), but under a potentially variable app context

I can think of the following solutions:

1. always use relative paths between assets.

   The problem with this is that if I ever move an asset, then all of its relative links must change.

   Another possible issue would be that, if I somehow made Asset Pipeline route proprietary assets to my own static server, and thrid-party assets to public CDNs (e.g., https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs for angularjs, jquery, etc.), then any static relative URLs wouldn't work.

   I assume that I shouldn't ever directly reference js and/or css files outside of Asset Pipeline manifests, so, unless that's wrong, then this problem shouldn't occur for those file types, but, if there's a CDN for common images (does such a thing exist?), then static relative URLs in html files wouldn't work in `img` `src` attributes.
2. angularjs & a javascript variable set via a gsp

   Use angularjs in the html file to read a javascript variable that contains the base URL.  Set the base URL in a gsp that is referenced by every page.

   The problems with this are:

   1. that a separate request for the gsp is necessary (though it should be able to be cached for a long time).  Is it possible to compile a gsp at build-time into a js file, and copy the result as an asset, so that it could be included in the Asset Pipeline static bundle rather than served from my Grails server?
   2. that browser cycles are used processing the angularjs code
   3. that certain third-party javascript libraries don't play well with angularjs, so it might be complex to get them working with this setup
   4. from what I know, `url()` calls in css would still have to be relative, since angularjs wouldn't be able to influence them.  Maybe I could use one of the css wrapper languages, like less, but this option is getting much more complicated than option 1...

Are there any other viable options?

Are there any other cons and/or gotchas to either option that I've mentioned above?

I'm using the current version of Asset Pipeline (2.2.5), and the latest version of Grails 2.x (2.5.0).